# Forgot password to id_rsa

Tags: macos, ssh, osx-lion

I forgot the password to my `ssh`. I am planning to remove the files `(id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts)` in the directory and starting from scratch. I haven't been using `ssh` since the whole heartbleed thing and I've cleared out the stuff in the keys before but I think I did it wrong.

My question is how do I recreate the files properly and set up `ssh` to stop asking me for passwords when I'm connecting to `git` or other things?

Comment: By the way, read ["Does Heartbleed affect ssh keys?"](http://superuser.com/q/739349/2357).

Comment: (already marked as dup. so can't answer properly) OS X may well have stored your passphrase in your keychain so you don't have to enter it each time you connect to a server.  Open *Keychain Access*, search for "id_rsa" and you should get a result with "SSH:/Users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa" (your private key) with "Kind" listed as "Application password".  You can do Edit > Copy password to clipboard to get it back.  You'll be asked for your "login keychain password" – which is just the one you use to login to the Mac's user account. To change passphrase: `cd ~/.ssh` and `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -p`

Comment: "Copy password to clipboard" didn't do anything for me!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to remove your SSH public/private keys, recreate them, and then add your newly created public key to the servers and online services you use.

- Remove your SSH public/private keys:

  ```
   rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
  ```
- Recreate the keypair, choosing a new passphrase:

  ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- Add the newly created private key to your OS X Keychain to store the passphrase and manage unlocking it automatically:

  ```
   ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- Copy the public key to the OS X clipboard for adding to web services like GitHub, etc.

  ```
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
  ```
- Add your newly created public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the remote server. Be sure to ensure the correct permissions of both the remote `~/.ssh` folder (`700`) and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (`600`). You may want to investigate using [`ssh-copy-id`](https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX) to ease this process.

Edited on 11/18/2021

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't need to reset it, I searched for id_rsa in my OS X Keychain, and clicked the show password icon.  Entered my root password & voila :)

Comment: For some reason OS X was giving me the wrong password when I used the method noted in the comment. So if that happens, definitely try the actual answer as it did solve the issue for me.

Comment: Funny thing - I got that "wrong password" issue as well.  It seems to be showing something "else" there.

Comment: @gef - thank you for saving me unnecessary grief and time. I wonder if this can be done on non-MacOSX machines in some way.